# boost version 1.54 boost::filesystem::directory_iterator, Trying to use is_directory function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

Using Linux OpenSUSE 12.3 32-bit

I'm going through Bartosz Milewski's c++11 concurrency videos on youtube.  In part 5 he uses his own filesystem.h file in an example where multiple threads are spawned to read all the files in a directory and its sub-directories.  So I decided to use boost's filesystem methods since I don't have access to his. I can't figure out how to call is_directory on a directory_iterator.

In fact I don't seem to have any of the regular methods for a directory iterator.  I'm using boost version 1.54 downloaded source from site.  I'm also using Qt Creator (2.8.1) and its auto-completion for a directory_iterator doesn't show any useful functions. I've used boost to get file_size() of a file, so I assume it was installed correctly.  I've also taken a look at what was deprecated and can't seem to find anything on directory_iterator.

I've tried

```
itr.is_directory
*itr.is_directory
boost::filesystem::is_directory(itr->status())    //doesn't have the member function status
boost::filesystem::is_directory(boost::filesystem::status(itr))
itr.status();
itr->status();
```

This is the code from Bartosz Milewski's example (not quite finished yet)

**test2.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
typedef std::vector<std::string> string_vector;
namespace fs=boost::filesystem;
string_vector listDirectory(std::string && dir)
{
    string_vector listing;
    std::string dirStr("\n> ");
    dirStr += dir;
    dirStr += ":\n";
    listing.push_back(dirStr);

    std::vector<std::future<string_vector>> futures;
    for (fs::directory_iterator itr(dir); itr !=fs::directory_iterator(); ++itr)
    {
```

if (itr.is_directory);  **this is where I need to find if its a directory**

```
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    return listing;
}

int main()
{
    std::string root= "/home/craig/";
    auto ftr = std::async(std::launch::async, &listDirectory, root);
    try
    {
        string_vector listing = ftr.get();

    }
}
```

auto-completion shows the following in Qt Creator (auto complete in brackets)

```
itr-> [mref, operator ->,operator Reference *,proxy]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
if (itr->status().type() == boost::filesystem::directory_file) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: as I said, there is no status function for directory_iterator  so that clearly won't work

Comment: actually I tried a dumbed down program and status apparently does work, sorry about that.  So really I have a qt creator question cause its not pulling in any of the functions for auto-completion.. which renders my whole question pointless

Comment: Many auto-completes often bug out (or take a long time) on complex C++ libraries, the code should compile just fine though if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

while I don't know how to get qt creator to auto-complete boost's filesystem directory_iterator, I wanted to post the working example program in case someone else ends up here.  Also note that root was changed to /home/craig/Documents since the directory above it resulted in too many threads to be able to run correctly ( Resource temporarily unavailable ) I think in the next part (part 6) Bartosz limits how many threads can be produced.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono> //don't need this, for this program, but is in the example
#include <vector>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

typedef std::vector<std::string> string_vector;
namespace fs=boost::filesystem;

string_vector listDirectory(std::string && dir)
{

    string_vector listing;
    std::string dirStr("\n> ");
    dirStr += dir;
    dirStr += ":\n";
    listing.push_back(dirStr);

    std::vector<std::future<string_vector>> futures;
    for (fs::directory_iterator itr(dir); itr !=fs::directory_iterator(); ++itr)
    {
        if (fs::is_directory(itr->status()))
        {

            auto ftr =std::async(std::launch::async,&listDirectory,std::move(itr->path().string()));
            futures.push_back(std::move(ftr));
        }
        else
        {
            listing.push_back(std::move(itr->path().filename().string()));
        }
    }
    for(auto &ftr:futures)
    {
        string_vector lst = ftr.get();
        std::move(lst.begin(),lst.end(),std::back_inserter(listing));

    }
    return listing;
}

int main()
{
    std::string root= "/home/craig/Documents/";
    auto ftr = std::async(std::launch::async, &listDirectory, std::move(root));
    try
    {
        string_vector listing = ftr.get();
        for (auto &s:listing)
        {
            std::cout << s << " ";
        }

    }
    catch(std::exception & e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "unknown exception" <<std::endl;
    }
}
```